# NetCore 3.1: How to execute python.exe using Process on Azure?

Tags: python, azure, asp.net-core, process

I have a NetCore3.1 server app. On my local setup I can use Process to execute python to do some dataframe crunching that I have installed in a venv.

On Azure, I can use site extensions to install a local copy of python and all my needed libs. (It's located in D:/home/python364x86/).

Now on my published Azure app, I want my process to execute python as on my local setup.  I have configured the proper path, but I get this error: "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: D. Path '', line 0, position 0."

Would anyone know why this is failing?  Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Post your code. The error complains about the string, not whether the path exists or not. Did you type the path or copied it from a web page which may include invisible characters? Did you escape the backslashes?

Comment: You should get the same error for the same path if you create a simple console application locally, or even try this in Visual Studio's C# Interactive window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please notice that the python extension is in the website extension, so it should be impossible to access the python extension in code.

Comment: I believe this is the case (and this is what I couldn't find documented anywhere, what locations are accessible). What I ended up doing was using py2exe to create an executable (not fully bundled, just a folder), unzipping the folder into wwwroot with all the rest of the dll's and then I can access my "script" from there behaving exactly as it does in my test env.  I see in Azure, you can make virtual paths, perhaps that's a way to link inaccessible paths?  I'm not sure...